# Maximum value of $(3 \cos(x - 0.730) -3)^2$

Tags: trigonometry

Maximum value of $(3 \cos(x - 0.730) -3)^2$

Maximum value of $(3\cos(x-0.730)$ is $3$ and minimum is $-3$

Conceptually , to find the maximum of $(3 \cos(x - 0.730) -3)^2$ is to use 
$(3-3)^2$ however that is $0$.

But when I use the minimum value - $(-3-3)^2) =36$ and 36 is the maximum value . But isn't this conceptually wrong to use the minimum value to find the maximum value ?

I do not understand why must we use $-3$ obviously squaring a negative number will give u a positive number . But is there a reason why must I use $-3$ ?

Comment: Why do you say "Conceptually, to find the maximum of $(3 \cos (x−0.730)−3)^2$ is to use $(3−3)^2$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of $(3 \cos(x - 0.730) -3)^2$ as the square of the distance between 
$3 \cos(x - 0.730)$ and $3$  And that distance will be maximized when $3 \cos(x - 0.730)$ is negative.  And the square of the distance will always be minimized when the two coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $y^2 = |y|^2$. So what you need to find is the maximum *magnitude* of $y$.

In this case, the cosine term is bounded by $[-1,1]$. You cannot change the $-3$ term, so your best option is to make the cosine term as negative as possible (a high magnitude negative number added to another negative number will give a higher magnitude negative number). The cosine term will be most negative when it is $-1$. Then the entire expression becomes $(3(-1) - 3)^2 = (-3-3)^2$. When squaring this, you know you'll end up with a positive value that's maximal.